# Understanding Limits and Colimits by Generalized Elements

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

We want to characterize the limit and colimit of a functor $D\colon J\to \mathcal C$ by generalized elements. The existence of limits theorem states that the limit of $D$ is the equalizer of $$s,t\colon \prod_{j\in Ob(J)}D(j)\to \prod_{f\in Ar(J)}D(\text{cod}(f))$$ where $s=\langle Df\circ\pi_{\text{dom}(f)} \rangle_{f\in Ar(J)}$ and $t=\langle \pi_{\text{cod}(f)}\rangle_{f\in Ar(J)}$. Equalizers are monic, and so we may think of the limit of $D$ as a subobject of the product $\prod D(j)$.

Moreover, the Yoneda embedding $y\colon \mathcal C\to Set^{\mathcal C^{op}}$ preserves all limits. Therefore, it is tempting to write the limit of $D$ by generalized elements (i.e. $x\in X$ means $x\in Ar(\mathcal C)$ with cod$(x)$=X) as
$$ \lim D = \left[x\in\prod D(j)| s(x)=t(x)\right].
$$

Unfortunately, the Yoneda embedding does not preserve colimits. However, the colimit of $D$ is a quotient object of the coproduct and I still feel tempted to write, 
$$ \text{colim } D = \frac{\coprod D(j)}{\sim},
$$
where $\sim = \bigcap [E:\text{equivalence relation} |\ \langle s(x), t(x)\rangle\in E]$ where the equivalence relations are taken on hom-sets. (And $s, t$ here are the dualized arrows of the maps above).

Is this the wrong characterization? Is there a good analogy between the colimit of an arbitrary functor and the colimit in sets? Is 
$$
   \frac{\mathcal C(\square,\coprod D(j))}{\sim}\colon \mathcal C^{op}\to Set
$$
a well-defined functor which is representable, i.e., isomorphic to $\mathcal C(\square,\text{colim } D)$?

Comment: I see this is the typical meaning of $\langle f \rangle_{f \in Ar(J)}$, and the notation for what I was looking for is $\prod_{f \in Ar(J)} f$ or $f \times g : X \times Y \to Z \times W$ for $f: X \to Z, g: Y \to W$.

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, the indexing sets have different sizes so such a product of arrows doesn't work here.

Comment: The indices of the product range over $j\in Ob(J)$.

Comment: Okay, so it's like $\pi_1:X \times Y \to X,$ not $\pi_X:X \times Y \to X$.

Comment: Why the intersection over equivalence relations instead of the singleton/complement relation?

Comment: Since we are trying to capture the colimit in terms of generalized elements, I was thinking taking Set-equivalence relations on $\mathcal C(X,\coprod D(j))$ for each $X\in \mathcal C$. Is it true that an internal equivalence is equivalent to equivalences on hom-sets for each object $X\in \mathcal C$?

Comment: $(x,y) \in E\ \iff x=y \text{ or } (x,y) \in \{(z,w),(w,z)\}$ for a fixed $(z,w)$. Internal is internal to $\text{Set}$ here, so it doesn't make anything new if it's hom sets in the equivalence...